# Geoprocess removing table and associated joins and definition queries from map in ArcGIS Pro project

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, attribute-joins, definition-query, overwriteoutput

I need a table join and definition query to be preserved after a scripting tool is run that overwrites the table. When the end user opens ArcGIS Pro no maps are active or open. However, when the tool is run and the map is subsequently opened, the table is gone. If I hit the undo button the table reappears twice. I have "Remove layers that reference data overwritten by geoprocessing tools" unchecked and have "Allow geoprocessing tools to overwrite existing datasets" checked.

Is there something else I need to do to preserve the table join and definition query even though the map is closed?

Comment: Is your table in an enterprise geodatabase? When you overwrite it, are there privileges that need to be added to the table so that you can view it in the project?

Comment: No. It's a fgdb table.

Comment: How are you saving the map (when the table is included on the map)?  How are you opening the map after the tool is run?

Comment: I'm saving the map using the disk icon on the upper lefthand corner. I'm opening the map through the catalog pane under the maps folder.